# Django loses connection to MySQL db after initialization (Docker)

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm starting to work with Docker, I'm running a Django app in a container, and a MySQL db in another one. Both of them are connected through a `docker-compose.yml` file.

After building the containers, Django migrations run successfully and the application starts properly.

However, if I connect to the Django container and execute a command (i.e. `python manage.py createsuperuser`) an `OperationalError` is raised saying that it is not possible to connect to the database. **What can be the problem?**

The picture below shows that tables are created in the database (at some point Django does have access to the db)

[image: Django can access the db and run migrations]

Accessing the **4rs_backend** container (Django) with `docker exec -it <container id> sh` and executing `python manage.py createsuperuser` raises:

[image]

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
   db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "7000:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_USER: admin_test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '*****'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '*****'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: forrealstate
    container_name: mysql_db
  api:
    build: backend
    command: bash -c "BUILD_TYPE='DOCKER' python manage.py makemigrations && BUILD_TYPE='DOCKER' python manage.py migrate && BUILD_TYPE='DOCKER' python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    container_name: 4rs_backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

DATABSE config in Settings.py:

```
BUILD_TYPE = os.environ.get('BUILD_TYPE')
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'forrealstate',
        'USER': 'admin_test' if BUILD_TYPE == 'DOCKER' else 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '********',
        'HOST': 'db' if BUILD_TYPE == 'DOCKER' else '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me!

Kind regards

**EDIT: Answer**

Fixed by adding `BUILT_TYPE: 'DOCKER'` as an environment variable in the api service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the DB connection depends on an environment variable `BUILD_TYPE`. In the `api` container it is set before executing the command. When you attach to the container, this variable is not set, so django uses the default 127.0.0.1 host.

Fix: prepend `BUILD_TYPE='DOCKER'` to all `manage.py` commands, e.g.:

```
BUILD_TYPE='DOCKER' python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Alternatively, set this variable globally in the container (that's what I would do)

Comment: if only i thoguht about this before asking... I added the variable as an environment var for that container and it worked. Thank you!